# Confusion regarding dependencies

Tags: normal-forms

Let say we have a relation with 5 attributes `{A, B, C, D, E}`. Let say we have two candidate keys as `A` and `B,C`. Let us say we have a partial dependency as `B -> E` with regards to the candidate key `B,C`. The database designer decides that A will be the primary key of the relation. Now since we had `B -> E`, will it be called a partial dependency or a transitive dependency? Is the relation `2NF` or not even `2NF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [definition of the 2NF is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form):

> **A functional dependency on part of any candidate key is a violation of 2NF**. In addition to the primary key, the relation may contain other candidate keys; it is necessary to establish that no non-prime attributes have part-key dependencies on any of these candidate keys.

This schema is not in 2NF.